# Pointing to struct in C - error: expected ')' before '*' token

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile this code (gonna be a simulation of Langton's Ant):

```
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    typedef struct
    {
        unsigned short x, y;
        enum directions {up = 0, right, down, left} direction;
    } langtonsAnt;

    void turnAnt (lantonsAnt *pant, unsigned short quarterTurns)
    {
        pant->direction = (pant->direction + quarterTurns) % 4;
    }

    int main ()
    {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> 12|error: expected ')' before '*' token|

The compiler is gcc.

I cannot figure out what's wrong as I already searched the web and various references.

P.S. Don't worry about the headers, those are needed elsewhere in the program.

Comment: lantonsAnt -> langtonsAnt?

Comment: Line 10: `langtosAnt`. Line 12: `lantosAnt`. Note the missing `g`...

Answer (score 7):

```
void turnAnt (lantonsAnt *pant, unsigned short quarterTurns)
```

should be

```
void turnAnt (langtonsAnt *pant, unsigned short quarterTurns)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a 'g' in your passed pointer to the function turnAnt! Notice the 'g' after "lan" in the struct name?

```
typedef struct
    {
        unsigned short x, y;
        enum directions {up = 0, right, down, left} direction;
    } langtonsAnt;
```

But then in your function turnAnt, " lantonsAnt *pant " is missing the 'g'! It should look like this:

```
void turnAnt (langtonsAnt *pant, unsigned short quarterTurns)
{
    ......
```